# Bulk delete users from a csv list

Tags: users, bulk, customization

I have a WordPress site with 65,000 registered users, about 10,000 of those users are spam bots, inactive account, hard email bonces etc.

I have them gathered in a CSV list, how can I use that csv list to delete those users from my WordPress site?

I haven't been able to find a plugin that does it.

Comment: What is the structure of your CSV?

Comment: Why don't you write the code yourself? You just have to loop through the CSV, match the data with the users table and delete users that match. That's beginner PHP/WordPress.

Comment: If you try and are stuck, you can always come back here :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
DELETE 
FROM  wp_users 
WHERE  ID in ( 5506, 5507,... );
```

Make sure to try it on a staging area first and backup your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete lots of users via SQL using emails:

```sql
DELETE 
FROM  wp_users 
WHERE  user_email in ( 'email@email.com', 'email2@gmail.com' );
```

You can generate list of emails in line via Excel.

Or, you can exclude using Usernames too:

```sql
DELETE 
FROM  wp_users 
WHERE  user_login in ( 'username1', 'username2', 'username3' );
```

Be sure to make a backup beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the [Stop Spammers plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stop-spammer-registrations-plugin/)

I have found that can be pretty effective - not 100% - but good at stopping spam registrations - you can add various APIs.

I don't think you can do the CSV thing you need specifically, but I'm pretty sure you can cut into your existing db - and prevent further spam registrations.

Side-note, I find CloudFlare is pretty good at protecting the sign up process from bots.

**Update:**

The plugin cannot delete existing users:

> Unfortunately, WordPress did not record the IP address of User registrations prior to version 5.0. This is a design flaw in WordPress. They do record the IP of comments. I cannot run a check against logins without their IP address, so you have to remove users the old fashioned way, one at a time. You might try listing the emails of all registered users, and then deleting them. You can then ask all users to re-register, but that would probably annoy your legitimate users.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a recommendation